# How to highlight a region of Interest in an image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am wondering how to highlight a mask/Region of Interest (or how to mark identified objects) in an image in Matlab at given/specified location?

Comment: Changed title to be more informative.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful command is [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html). Suppose `rect` holds the bounding box around the object (in format `[ from_x from_y width height]`), then the following code will produce a box around the object in the image:

```
figure('Name', 'showing detected object');
imshow( img ); % show original image
hold all;  % hold image and plot rectangle on top
rectangle( 'Position', rect );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have all the vertexes of the region you are interested in you can simply use the `line` command. I post you how to draw a rectangle having the four vertexes (each a pair of x,y coordinates).

```
rect1=[a';b';c';d';a'];

line(rect1(:,1),rect1(:,2),'LineWidth',5);
```

I don't know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to select a region on an image, then you can use the functions:

```
imrect
impoly
imellipse
imline
```

from the Image Processing toolkit.